# What is the difference (if any) between 'harmonized' and 'standardized data?

Tags: terminology, database, references

I am trying to describe the process of combining multiple datasets into a common format - e.g. a single database that enforces a common vocabulary, scale, and structure.

However, I am unclear if I should refer to the resulting database as 'harmonized', 'standardized', or some other term.

On the one hand, 'standardize' seems to be less jargony (and more familiar) than 'harmonize'. On the other hand, the idea of data 'standards' is conflated with the concept of community-adopted standards.

I have found one abstract ([Fuertes 2008](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13876980802468766))that provides the following distinction:

> The main difference between harmonization and standardization processes lies in the degree of strictness of the accounting standards. Harmonization involves a reduction in accounting variations, while standardization entails moving towards the eradication of any variation.

However, this is not particularly clear. When are each of these terms appropriate? Is there a canonical reference for parsing these concepts?

Comment: "Standardize" is highly ambiguous in this context, because (a) it has a conventional statistical meaning (in terms of changing the units of measurement of data so that they have a mean of zero and unit variance) whereas (b) your question seems to have little or nothing to do with that.  Do you have a definition of "standardize" you can offer to help us understand what you're asking?  The issue with "harmonize" is that it has no commonly understood meaning, making it essential that you offer a definition.

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering this same thing and came across these two answers:

"The purpose of data standardization is to make your data consistent and clear. Consistent is ensuring that the output is reliable so that related data can be identified using common terminology and format. Clear is to ensure that the data can be easily understood by those who are not involved with the data maintenance process." -Oracle.com

"Data harmonization is the classic use case for MDM and refers to the process of combining multiple data sources into an integrated, unambiguous entity “golden copy” record that can be used by consuming systems to feed a business process." - Kalido.com